# code improvement - naming textboxes generated form numericupdown & button click

Tags: c#, .net

I have a problem with a code that is regarding adding controls with numericUpDown ( for example- if numericUpDown value equals to 3, user recievs 3 textboxes).

Thanks to stackoverflow users I improved my code.

Before improvement it looked like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

{

```
if (numericUpDown1.Value == 1)
{
    txtbx1.AutoSize = true;
    Controls.Add(txtbx1);
    txtbx1.Location = new Point(70, 100);
}
else if (numericUpDown1.Value == 2)
{
    txtbx1.AutoSize = true;
    Controls.Add(txtbx1);
    txtbx1.Location = new Point(70, 100);

    txtbx2.AutoSize = true;
    Controls.Add(txtbx2);
    txtbx2.Location = new Point(70, 130);
}
else if (numericUpDown1.Value == 3)
{
    txtbx1.AutoSize = true;
    Controls.Add(txtbx1);
    txtbx1.Location = new Point(70, 100);

    txtbx2.AutoSize = true;
    Controls.Add(txtbx2);
    txtbx2.Location = new Point(70, 130);

    txtx3.AutoSize = true;
    Controls.Add(txtbx3);
    txtbx3.Location = new Point(70, 160);
}
```

}

After improvement:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

{

```
int y = 100;
int x = 70;
for (int i = 0; i < numericUpDown1.Value; i++)
{
    var txtbx = new TextBox();
    txtbx.AutoSize = true;
    Controls.Add(txtbx);
    txtbx.Location = new Point(x, y);

    // Increase the y-position for next textbox.
    y += 30;
}
```

}

Now the problem is that I don't know how assign names to genarated textboxes.
(before the improvement I could name them - txtbx1, txtbx2, txtbx3...)

Code to improve:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    try
    {
        double a, b, c, sum;

        a = double.Parse(txtbx1.Text);
        b = double.Parse(txtbx2.Text);
        c = double.Parse(txtbx3.Text);

        sum = a + b + c;
        label1.Text = sum.ToString();



    }

    catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("error");
        }
```

Please note that I'm a beginner, learning c# by watching youtube tutorials ;) I do realize that my question might be silly but I couldn't handle this problem by myself.

In advance thank you for your time and help.

Comment: He probably means to access them via variable name from outisde the for loop. I'm a bit rusty on winforms, but `(TextBox)this.Controls.First(c => c.Name == "textBox1")` should work, if, as you said, `txtbx`'s name is correctly set to `"textBox" + i` inside the loop.

Comment: It usually helps to look at the way other programs implemented their UI.  Surely you have a bunch of programs you like to use frequently.  Ever saw one that had a NUD that lets you pick the number of text boxes you can type stuff into?  You've got a 150 horsepower chain-saw in your hand.  There isn't anything you cannot mow down with it.  It just needs to make sense to somebody *else*.  If it doesn't even make sense to *you* then it is probably a good idea to put the safety back on.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to access them afterwards, you have some options.
I'll guess that your objective is to **set label1's text to the sum of the values contained in the specified textbox(es)**.

On the `ValueChanged` event of your `NumericUpDown`, check the *delta* and consequentely add or remove the required number of `TextBoxes` to your `Form`'s `Controls`. To obtain the *delta*, you'll need to store the previous value of the `NumericUpDown`, and then subtract it from the current value. (If it was 5, and now it's 4, 4 - 5 = -1. A textbox has been removed).

```
    private int _oldNUDvalue = 0; //or assign it to the default value
    private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int delta = (int)numericUpDown1.Value - _oldNUDvalue;
        if (delta < 0)
        {
            for (int i = -delta; i > 0; i--)
            {
                var tbox = Controls.Find("ntextBox" + (_oldNUDvalue - i), false)[0];
                Controls.Remove(tbox);
            }
        }
        else if (delta > 0)
        {
            for (int i = _oldNUDvalue; i < _oldNUDvalue + delta; i++)
            {
                var tbox = new TextBox();
                tbox.Location = new Point(15, 55 + (30 * i));
                tbox.Name = "ntextBox" + i;
                Controls.Add(tbox);
            }
        }
        _oldNUDvalue = (int)numericUpDown1.Value;
    }
```

If, however, you only have a maximum number of 3, you could take a slightly different approach. My solution works with *n-textboxes*.

Finally, to get the `TextBox`es' values from code, you have three approaches:

> Loop through your Form's controls, check for TextBoxes with their name starting with "ntextBox", and add their values together
>
> Use LINQ to do the same
>
> Access them singularly via "Controls.Find("ntextBoxX", false)", where X is the number of course.

I'll show the LINQ approach as I like it better.

```
int sum = Controls.Cast<Control>().Sum(c => c.Name.StartsWith("ntextBox") ? int.Parse(c.Text) : 0);
```

I haven't tested the code, but it should work. Tell me if there are any problems.

EDIT: Tested and it works. For the sake of completeness, I'll add some event logic to the TextBox-adding loop, to make sure that their input is actually numeric.

```
tbox.TextChanged += HandleNTextBoxInput; // add this line
```

And elsewhere, add this method:

```
void HandleNTextBoxInput(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string text = ((TextBox)sender).Text;
    if (!Regex.IsMatch(text, "^[1-9][0-9]*$")) //Text is NOT numeric. Remove [1-9] if you want to keep leading zeros.
    {
       //Set the Text to 0, for example. Or show a message box. Or whatever.
       ((TextBox)sender).Text = "0";
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your time and help. This code seems to be difficult, and I actually have some problems with it. I know that copy- paste shouldn't be difficult, but this code is very advanced (at least for me). Could you tell me what I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in a comment- this code seems to be maybe too advanced for me.

I have no problem with adding the controls, bu still there is a problem how to get the sum from a button click to a textbox.

I probably made some simple mistakes, or something is missing but I really don't know how to fix this problem.

My code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace testprogram
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }



    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // I'm guessing something is missing over here

    {
        int sum = Controls.Cast<Control>().Sum(c => c.Name.StartsWith("ntextBox") ? int.Parse(c.Text) : 0);


    }
    void HandleNTextBoxInput(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string text = ((TextBox)sender).Text;
        if (!Regex.IsMatch(text, "^[1-9][0-9]*$")) //Text is NOT numeric. Remove [1-9] if you want to keep leading zeros.
        {
            //Set the Text to 0, for example. Or show a message box. Or whatever.
            ((TextBox)sender).Text = "0";
        }
    }
    private int _oldNUDvalue = 0; //or assign it to the default value
    private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        {
            int delta = (int)numericUpDown1.Value - _oldNUDvalue;
            if (delta < 0)
            {
                for (int i = -delta; i > 0; i--)
                {
                    var tbox = Controls.Find("ntextBox" + (_oldNUDvalue - i), false)[0];
                    Controls.Remove(tbox);
                }
            }
            else if (delta > 0)
            {
                for (int i = _oldNUDvalue; i < _oldNUDvalue + delta; i++)
                {
                    var tbox = new TextBox();
                    tbox.Location = new Point(15, 55 + (30 * i));
                    tbox.Name = "ntextBox" + i;
                    tbox.TextChanged += HandleNTextBoxInput;
                    Controls.Add(tbox);
                }
            }
            _oldNUDvalue = (int)numericUpDown1.Value;
        }


    }
}
```

}